# How to add a person into Google Group Chat using webhooks

Tags: python, webhooks

I have a chat and I want to use webhooks to add people into it.

I have tried tagging a user that was not in the chat but that did not work

```
from httplib2 import Http
from json import dumps
print()
import os
os.system('clear')
#messageinput = input('Message: ')

#
# Hangouts Chat incoming webhook quickstart
#
amp = 1
while amp == 1:
  def main():
    url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAHDmEsoI/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=YpCZyYAzFiTmZhFgs_KLGv8A1qcNFlZLVcUMNkswMCo%3D'
    bot_message = {
        'text' : 'Hi <users/113438975428215985106>'}

    message_headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

    http_obj = Http()

    response = http_obj.request(
        uri=url,
        method='POST',
        headers=message_headers,
        body=dumps(bot_message),
    )

    print(response)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

  os.system('clear')
  print('Message sent as FBI Agent!')
  amp = amp + 1
```

The code did not work to add people

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, i can tell you webhooks are not designed for that, incoming webhook is designed to send messages simply without doing complicated codes, thats the goal from incoming webhook.

and if you read the Hangouts Webhook Docs, you must've seen this:

> Incoming webhooks let you send asynchronous messages into Hangouts Chat from applications that aren't bots themselves. For example, you can configure a monitoring application to notify oncall personnel on Hangouts Chat when a server goes down. Incoming webhooks serve as a quick and easy way to integrate with existing workflows such as these without the overhead of writing entire bot applications.

So what you want is not sending a message, what you want is bigger than this, so i suggest using Hangouts API which might help you.

Configure the API, get the credentials, and read the docs ;)